# Twisted SSH curl "'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: python, curl, ssh, twisted, createprocess

I've used twisted to make an SSH server similar to the one shown [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/SSH-with-Twisted/). I attempted to add curl functionality to it like so:

```
class CurlProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.closeStdin()

def do_curl(self, *args):
    "Sets up a download"
    curlProcess = CurlProcessProtocol()
    args = tuple(['curl'])+args
    reactor.spawnProcess(curlProcess, 'curl', args)
```

I have the files necessary for curl to run in the same directory as my program. When I connect to the SSH server and attempt a curl command, I get the following error: `Error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')` I tried appending `os.getcwd()+` before `'curl'` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I needed to be more specific. Here is a working do_curl. I had to add a "\" after getcwd() and a ".exe" after curl.

```
def do_curl(self, *args):
    "Sets up a download"
    curlProcess = CurlProcessProtocol()
    args = tuple([os.getcwd()+'\curl.exe'])+args
    reactor.spawnProcess(curlProcess, os.getcwd()+'\curl.exe', args)
```

Comment: You should do this with `os.path.join`, not `+`.  On UNIX-like OSes, you'd need a `/`, not a `\`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have to do it separately for Unix though, because Windows requires that I append ".exe"

Answer (score 2):

Try using the actual path to the curl executable.  Most likely it is not in `os.getcwd()`.  `/usr/bin` is more likely (or possibly `/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or some other system-defined location).  You can probably find it by using `which curl` in a shell.

Or, add the PATH environment variable to your `spawnProcess` call -

```
reactor.spawnProcess(
    curlProcess, 'curl', args, env={b"PATH": os.environ[b"PATH"]})
```

Or, probably even better, add your entire environment:

```
reactor.spawnProcess(
    curlProcess, 'curl', args, env=os.environ)
```

`PATH` controls where the system looks for relative path names like "curl" when trying to execute them.  If it is unset, you have to specify an absolute path to be able to execute anything.

Comment: The curl executable is in the cwd. I put it there.

Comment: If it really were, and you specified the absolute path to it, then spawnProcess would find it.  So something is not setup how you think.  Perhaps you forgot to put a "/" in between `os.getcwd()` and `"curl"`.  I don't know, you didn't exactly include that code in your question (but what you did include mixed in with your prose suggests you may have done this).